# Paypal subscription button customization

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to setup a paypal BuyNow/Subscribe button for my website, but cant seem to figure out if I can customize it the way I want.

The user will select one of my products on the website, and buy the hardware.  The hardware includes 3 months of free service.  After the three months, I would like the user to be automatically subscribed and be billed the monthly rate.

For example.  I am selling a cell phone, that costs 100$.  The user purchases a green cell phone, they will receive 3 months of service.  After the three months, the user will be billed 20$ per month for the service fee.

Has anyone been able to get this scenario to work?  If not, does anyone know of a service that would support my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PayPal Subscription button. Bascially you will need to offer 3 months trial(free) peroid and charge for the remaning months accordingly.

Just login to www.paypal.com->My selling Tools->Click "Update" beside PayPal buttons.
Create a Subscription button as per the below screenshot.
Note: Offer 3 months trial period with amount set to `0`

[image]